# spark executors running multiple copies of the same application

Tags: apache-spark

In the [spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/cluster-overview.html) it says,

> Each application gets its own executor processes, which stay up for the duration of the whole application and run tasks in multiple threads. This has the benefit of isolating applications from each other, on both the scheduling side (each driver schedules its own tasks) and executor side (tasks from different applications run in different JVMs). However, it also means that data cannot be shared across different Spark applications (instances of SparkContext) without writing it to an external storage system.

From the phrase

> ... executor side (tasks from different applications run in different
> JVMs)

Does this mean that

- If you're running multiple copies(multiple `spark-submit`s) of the same application in a cluster that has many executors, is it possible for an executor to run tasks that belong to different `spark-submit`s in parallel?
- If the above is possible, using singleton objects that are shared between tasks of an executor, can cause data collisions between different copies(different `spark-submit`s) of the same application?

Comment: No, this is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Each executor is separate JVM process, and only used for one application. No need to worry about data collision.